# Changing the default plot colour in r

Tags: r

When generate plots in R, the default colour which is used is green rather than black. I have been using R for a number of years and have recently changed computers and have only recently experienced this problem. For a range of settings I know I can manually change the colour to black, but I am wondering if there is a global setting which needs to be changed? Below is an example dataset which is experiencing the problem. In case it helps to diagnose the problem, when I explicitly call the points as "black", they do register as black. But I am unsure how to change the colour of the margins of my plots to black and would like to how to change my default colour from green to black. Apologies if this question seems basic, but I have looked everywhere an have not been able to find documentation on this problem.

```
df <- data.frame("ID" = 1:16)
df$A <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,16)
df$B <- c(7,9,10,8,11,12,14,13,15,4,5,3,6,2,16,1)
df

plot(df$A, df$B)
```

[image: Using default settings points and plot margin is green]

Below I explicitly change the point colour to black, and it does change the colour correctlyy.

```
plot(df$A, df$B, col = "black")
```

When I explicitly define the points as black they do turn black, but the margins remain as green.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably your global `par(fg)` options have been altered, try to change them back.

```
par(fg="black")  ## set to black
par()$fg
# [1] "black"
```

*Demonstration:*

```
op <- par(fg="green", mfrow=c(1, 2))
par()$fg
# [1] "green"
plot(1:10)
par(fg="black")
plot(1:10)
par(op)
```

[image]